# THREE.JS: How can I disable the dragControls after activating them on group of elements?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a function that activates the dragControls, while the "m" key is pressed. For some reason it is not deactivated when the "m" is unpressed. How can I disable the dragControls?

I have tried to encapsulate the dragControls to be activated if the statement is true, else dragControls = null. But whenever the first activation happens, it is not deactivated, even when the statement is false.
While and do while loops are just freezing the browser.

```
  init() {
  // EVENT LISTENERS:
  map.addEventListener('mousedown', this.movePoi, false);
  document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onDocumentKeyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onDocumentKeyUp, false);

},

// HELPER FUNCTIONS:
onDocumentKeyDown(event) {

  let keycode = event.which;
  if (keycode === 77) {
    this.moveIt = true;
    this.controls.enabled = false;
    console.log("Key is pressed");
    console.log(this.moveIt);
  }
},
onDocumentKeyUp(event){
  let keycode = event.which;
  console.log(keycode);
  if (keycode === 77) {
    this.moveIt = false;
    this.controls.enabled = true;
    console.log("Key is unpressed");
    console.log(this.moveIt);
  }
},
mouseOverScene (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  this.mouse.x = ( x / this.mapWidth) * 2 - 1;
  this.mouse.y = - ( y / this.mapHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  this.rayCaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
},

//POI movement around the scene:

movePoi (event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  let controlsDrag;
  if (this.moveIt) {
  controlsDrag = new DragControls(this.spheres, this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);

  } else {
    controlsDrag = null;
  }
}
```

EXPECTED: the objects should be dragged around by the left-click mouse, while the "m" key is pressed (the orbitControls are also disabled when this happens. This part works fine). When the "m" is not pressed, they should return the undraggable state and the orbitControls are enabled again.

ACTUAL: All of the above happens, BUT the objects are still draggable after the "m" is unpressed. The orbitControls are obviously enabled, which brings the whole next level of haywireness happening on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution goes as following:

```js
  init() {
  
        this.controlsDrag  = new DragControls(this.spheres, this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
      this.controlsDrag.deactivate();
      
  // EVENT LISTENERS:
  
      map.addEventListener('mousedown', this.startMovePoi, false);
      this.controlsDrag.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopMovePoi,false);
},

//POI movement around the scene:
    startMovePoi () {
      let controls = this.controls;
      this.controlsDrag.activate();
      this.controlsDrag.addEventListener('dragstart', function () {
        controls.enabled = false;
      });
      this.controlsDrag.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
        controls.enabled = true;
      });
    },
    
    
    stopMovePoi(){
      this.controlsDrag.deactivate();
    }
```

Needed some code refactoring before.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but you should try calling the movePoi function at the end of onDocumentKeyUp. At a glance it seems like the verification of whether "m" is pressed or not is only made when the mouse left button is clicked and not when the "m" key is unpresssed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped me to figure out what I needed to change!